# onStopTrackingTouch is getting called automatically after onStartTrackingTouch method in Seekbar without lifting the finger

Tags: android, gesture, android-seekbar

I have an app that uses android `SeebBar` to show and change `MediaPlayer` progress.

**Problem:**

When i touch and drag seek bar thumb sometimes it works perfectly and my MediaPlayer progress change successfully but some times when I touch and drag seek bar thumb it shows the pressed state ripple effect but does not change its position and feels life it got stuck.

I tried logging to detect the problem then I found `onStopTrackingTouch` is getting called automatically after `onStartTrackingTouch` method in Seekbar without lifting the finger and `onProgressChanged` not getting called.

**Code:**

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
              Log.d(">>>>>>", "I'm in onStartTrackingTouch");                 
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int seekPosition, boolean fromUser) {
              Log.d(">>>>>>", "I'm in onProgressChanged");                 

             // Here i'm just changing seek position of MediaPlayer     
             // but sometimes it invokes successfully sometimes it doesn't :(            
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
              Log.d(">>>>>>", "I'm in onStopTrackingTouch");                 
        }
    });
```

**Output:**

Sometimes I get:

```
 >>>>>>  I'm in onStartTrackingTouch
 >>>>>>  I'm in onProgressChanged
 >>>>>>  I'm in onProgressChanged
 >>>>>>  I'm in onProgressChanged 
 >>>>>>  ... 
 >>>>>>  I'm in onStopTrackingTouch
```

and sometimes:

```
 >>>>>>  I'm in onStartTrackingTouch
 >>>>>>  I'm in onStopTrackingTouch
```

still my finger pressed down and `onProgressChanged` just doesn't invoke.

Comment: Can you post some more details, like what what the limits on this SeekBar are, if you're doing any multithreading, etc?